How to Enable Spring WebClient to send all TLS 1.2 supported ciphers

I'm using Spring WebClient to communicate with an external server and it's a 2-way TLS connection.
My concern is WebClient is sending only 11 ciphers while TLSv1.2 supports many others. I know I can add ciphers myself to SslContextBuilder. Is there any way to instruct WebClient to add all TLSv1.2 ciphers by default?
return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .protocols(tlsV12)
            .ciphers("custom-ciphers") // Want to avoid it
            .keyManager(kmf)
            .trustManager(tm)
            .build();

